# Pass 'this' object to an initialization list

Tags: c++, constructor, reference, initialization-list

I've reduced the problem down to the following sample code:

```
class Charizard { //truck
    trainer &myTrainer;
  public:
    Charizard(trainer &tMyTrainer);
};

class trainer {
    Charizard myPokemon;
  public:
    trainer();
};

Charizard::Charizard(trainer &tMyTrainer) : myTrainer(tMyTrainer) {}
```

Without changing or adding public members, how can I create the constructor for trainer, such that when myPokemon is created in the initialization list, the "myTrainer" points back to the trainer being created?

Here is what I tried:

```
trainer::trainer() : myPokemon(this) {}
```

But of course "this" is not the correct type. I cannot change what the Charizard constructor takes in (it's a public member), so I'm not sure what to do. Any ideas?

Note: Title might need some work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need an instance object instead of a pointer, try:

```
trainer::trainer() : myPokemon(*this) {}
```

Be careful if `Charizard` tries to call any methods on `tMyTrainer` in its constructor, because your new `trainer` object has not yet been fully constructed at that time.

Answer (score 4):

A reference type is expected - just use `*this` instead of `this`.

A lot of compilers will warn about this anyway: `myPokemon` will be constructed before `trainer` is done, so it gets a reference to a non-constructed `trainer`. Be careful not to call any methods on it (or use its data) since it leads to undefined behavior!