# Pass instance of an object to member during initialization using *this

Tags: c++, initialization, this

Having some trouble with passing the this pointer of a class instance of class A. The goal here is for class B to have access to the members of class A instance objA.

```
class B
{
public:
    B(A _objA)
        : objA(_objA) {;}

        A objA;
};

class A
{
public:
    A() : objB(*this) {;}

    B objB;
};


int main() {
    A Object;
}
```

Compiling this gives
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'A'

Tried following [Pass 'this' object to an initialization list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356690/pass-this-object-to-an-initialization-list) for reference without luck. Could it just be a linking issue?

Comment: for `class B`, you are using an `A` object before the compiler knows what an `A` is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have stated, A is not defined before it is used. However, you could use a forward declaration of A to allow B to contain a reference to A. It will still be an incomplete type in the class definition of B. But you can move B's constructor outside of the class definition. class A will be a complete type and you can access it's members. Example:

```
// forward declaration 
class A;

class B
{
public:
    B(A &_objA);

        // reference
        A &objA;
};

class A
{
public:
    A() : objB(*this) {;}

    B objB;
    int count;
};

// implementation moved outside of the class definition
B::B(A &_objA) : objA(_objA)
{
    // class A is now a complete type and we can access
    // elements using the reference
    objA.count = 42;
}

int main() {
    A Object;
}
```

*Edit

If you want to put class definition in header files, you have a couple options. You could have a single common header file that would look much like the above code example. Alternatively, you could have a header file per class definition. Just make sure you include the header files in the correct order.

```
/* header file A.h */
#ifndef __A_H
#define __A_H

// class A needs the definition of class B
#include "B.h"

class A
{
public:
    A();

    B objB;
    int count;
};
#endif /* __A_H */
```

Don't forget the forward declaration in B's header file:

```
/* header file B.h */
#ifndef __B_H
#define __B_H

class A;

class B
{
public:
    B(A &_objA);

        // reference
        A &objA;
};
#endif /* __B_H */
```

Finally, just include the headers in each implementation file. Since A.h includes B.h, you really only need `#include "A.h"`. However, I like to be explicit and include them both.

```
/* implementation file A.cpp */
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

A::A() : objB(*this)
{
}
```

Comment: Also, having somewhat of an issue when factoring these out into separate files (*.hh, *.cpp etc) even with def guards. Looks like it's having problems with the declaration of objB inside class A..

Comment: Ah, the issue was that, again, the B's constructor needs to follow the implementation of Class A. Thus, putting Class B's constructor in the Class A cpp file did the trick.

Comment: Just make sure you are including the header files when needed. I updated the answer with some additional information on how to separate a class definition and implementation.

Answer (score 4):

That's not going to work.  `A` contains an instance of `B`, and `B` contains an instance of `A`.  There's no way to construct an object of either type, since they're recursively defined.

Another problem is that you're passing `*this` by value from inside the initialization list of `A`'s constructor.  This will invoke `A`'s copy constructor, which will result in undefined behaviour because the instance of `A` hasn't been fully constructed yet.

Comment: OK, this makes sense. But isn't this kind of behavior implemented fairly often in C#? Is there an equivalent way to do this?

Comment: pughar's solution below is the C# equivalent. Thanks